# "Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/user" - how to force sshd accept auth despite "wrong" permissions?

Tags: ssh, permissions, sshd, key-authentication

For some reasons, I NEED the home directory of some particular user to be group-writable. However, when trying to login to that user with ssh key, sshd refuses the authentication, as it **requires** the home directory to be writable by noone else than owner. In case it is group- or world-writable, sshd rejects authentication with the (in)famous message "Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/user".

Is there any way (except recompiling sshd) to **force** it to accept key authentication even when home directory is group-writable? Maybe place ssh keys in a different directory, outside of user's home dir, and tell sshd to use these keys?

Comment: Perhaps a better approach would be to move that user's `AuthorizedKeysFile` to a different location (a typical alternative is something like `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u` )

Comment: @steeldriver But can this be changed only for a single user, while leaving other users' authorized keys file in default location? If yes, that would be definitely the best approach. My impression was that `AuthorizedKeysFile` is a global setting for all users.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible with a `Match user` directive

Comment: @steeldriver Looks that it won't work :( sshd refuses to start with a message: Directive 'AuthorizedKeysFile' is not allowed within a Match block. But I found another solution :) I will describe it.

Comment: That's odd - I checked before posting and it's included in the *"subset of keywords [that] may be used on the lines following a Match keyword"* in the sshd man page

Comment: @steeldriver Maybe you have a newer version of sshd. My man page doesn't list `AuthorizedKeysFile` there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution myself :) There are in fact two different possibilities.

First is to set the option `StrictModes` to `no` (default is `yes`) in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. With that setting, sshd does not enforce permissions on users home dir. The downside of this method is that it is global for all users.

The second method is to use the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` option. We need to write a simple script, that for that particular user name (it is pased to the script as a first parameter) will output that user's authorized keys file - whenever it is located - and for other values of the first parameter it will simply do nothing. Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = "user" ]; then
  cat /usr/local/etc/users_authorized_keys
fi
```

If the script is placed for example in `/usr/local/libexec/listkeys`, then we need to put the following line into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/local/libexec/listkeys
```

With that solution, `/home/user` directory can be group writable, while for other users the permissions for home directory are still enforced.